# Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 403. with RSelenium in Firefox

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I have been running this code at all times it worked for me, but suddenly it returns the following error:

> Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 403

I haven't changed anything and I don't know why it could have happened. Any suggestion? Thank you!

```
 #Loading the rvest package
    library(rvest)
    library(magrittr) # for the '%>%' pipe symbols
    library(RSelenium) # to get the loaded html of 
    library(purrr) # for 'map_chr' to get reply 
    
    url_google <- list('https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.acsi.europa&hl=es&gl=US&showAllReviews=true')
    
    for (apps in url_google) { 
    
      #Specifying the url for desired website to be scraped
      url <- apps
    
      # starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
      selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
      shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
      remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
      remDr$open()
      
      require(RSelenium)
    
      # go to website
      remDr$navigate(url)
    
      
      # get page source and save it as an html object with rvest
      html_obj <- remDr$getPageSource(header = TRUE)[[1]] %>% read_html()
      
      # 1) App name
      app <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".AHFaub") %>% html_text()
      
      # 2) name field (assuming that with 'name' you refer to the name of the reviewer)
      names <- html_obj %>% html_nodes(".kx8XBd .X43Kjb") %>% html_text()
```

Comment: which data are you trying to extract?

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me was instead of your

```
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox")
  remDr$open()
```

I used

```
rD <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
                 check = FALSE
                 )
  remDr <- rD[["client"]]
```

The `rsDriver` command isn't the solution, but the argument `check = FALSE`.
At least for me, this was a `curl` issue, where it was trying to download new versions of each of the browser drivers and was having an issue.  Turning `check` to FALSE turns that download process off.